# How to set up an SFTP server for access from outside my own team?

Tags: sftp

I am working on SFTP(protocol). My team lead asked me. By using SFTP other division employees in my organization should access the files of our division documents i.e. They can download the documents from our division and upload the documents also how to achieve this. I worked on it but it is happening in my local machine only.

I came to know that in order to access the public network we have to set the public IP address in the firewall.
How to achieve to access the public network

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By using Secure File Transfer Protocol  I have to upload / download files from public network.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1679888/edit) your post and add more information about your setup, network connection, what you have done in your computer and in the firewall.

Comment: If the question really is "how to", the answer in a nutshell is "You need to set up an SFTP server and allow connectivity through your firewall". There are WAY too many variables (different OS:s, physical or virtual, multiple available SFTP server solutions, network setup, different firewalls etc.) to give straight step-by-step instructions here. Those can be found all over the internet.